# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Bytecode enhancement failed: echosign.agreement.Participation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, nhibernate-mapping

I am doing migration from Hibernate 5.2 to 5.5.7, with hibernate5.2 its is working properly but in hibernate 5.5.7 i am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Bytecode enhancement failed: public.part.participation
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.getProxy(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5130) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1215) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad$EntityResolver.lambda$static$0(TwoPhaseLoad.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1201) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1009) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1443) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor613.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.getProxy(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5130) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1215) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad$EntityResolver.lambda$static$0(TwoPhaseLoad.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1201) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1009) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1443) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at echosign.agreement.Participation.<init>(Participation.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
at echosign.agreement.Participation$HibernateProxy$nSeFPjS8.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor613.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.getProxy(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5130) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1215) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad$EntityResolver.lambda$static$0(TwoPhaseLoad.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1201) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1009) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1443) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.7.Final.jar:5.5.7.Final]
```

```html
@JsonSerialize(using = StubbableSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = StubbableDeserializer.class)
public class Participation extends AbstractParticipation implements Eventable, Stubbable,Cloneable
{
  @Override
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
  }

  public Participation()
  {
    setCreated(new Date());
    setIsRoot(Boolean.TRUE);

    **setObserverState(new ObserverState());**
    getObserverState().setNotified(Boolean.FALSE);
    getObserverState().setExposed(Boolean.FALSE);

  }
}
```

[Debugger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcBiq.png)

Can anyone help me , what i am missing here? I have checked all the dependencies and Byte-Buddy versions all seems ok.
I am not able to figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: That's the entire stack trace?

Comment: @tgdavies i have posted the entire stack trace

Comment: You have an NPE: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at echosign.agreement.Participation.<init>(Participation.java:103) ~[classes/:?]`

Comment: Yes, the stack trace shows Participation$HibernateProxy$nSeFPjS8.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:?]
When ever this proxy is generated , the class is not able to call its parent class methods and its giving NPE. I am not able to figure out why it is happening @tgdavies

Comment: Without seeing the code that is throwing the NPE, it is hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: setObserverState(new ObserverState()) is in super class and when ever Participation$HibernateProxy$nSeFPjS8 is generated , it is unable to call that setter method and giving NPE. @tgdavies

Comment: I had to do lazy=false for resolving the issue @tgdavies

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `lazy=false` to resolve the issue in my hibernate-mapping.xml for `Participation` class.

Comment: Had the same problem with some of my domain classes in Grails 5.3.2 (Hibernate 5.6.11.Final) a `static mapping = { myOtherClass lazy: false}` solved the issues. Do not fully understand why, but it helped.